# Login through facebook into other sites - IPHONE

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication

I have an application where i need to login to a website through facebook, twitter and the website's own login.

I'm not very sure how to login through facebook and connect it to the website. Like if i click on login with facebook button, it redirects to facbook login page( which is achievable with all the tutorials and information provided in the facebook developer documentation and the sdk) and then it is redirected to the website immediately after facebook login. 
How to achieve this? Any suggestions or help to achieve this will well appreciated.

I also would want to know about the encrypted access token of facebook. How to use that access token. I have read the documentation, yet i have not got the concept so clear in my head.

**EDIT**: the website is already connected to facebook and twitter... I have to to the same on iphone.. I mean, the response i will get after login through facebook is an access token.  Can i use this access token. How to link the response got after facebook login to the website to authenticate a user's login. This i need to do it in iphone.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example on how to do it with php,

[Facebook as Auth](http://subirkumarsao.blogspot.dk/2011/11/facebook-as-oauth.html)

EDIT: 
As you mention you already have a website in place with facebook and twitter integration and only require to do it in iPhone.

For iPhone have a look at facebook sdk for iPhone.

What you get after a authentication from facebook in iPhone app will be a access_token. You can use this token to get the facebook userid. Match the same id with the one present in the website. This way you can validate a user.

For getting user details from acess_token try this.

```
graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=<token>.
```

This will return basic user information along with facebook userid.

Best of luck.